# How to resolve SymPy importing error in Spyder and Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I'm trying to import sympy in both Spyder and Jupyter Notebooks (downloaded both through the Anaconda distribution). But, when I try to run the code (see below), I keep getting an ImportError saying that: " cannot import name 'Point2D' from 'sympy.geometry.point'". When I run this in Google CoLab, there is no such problem. How do I fix this issue? Sorry if there is an easy fix; I'm just getting into coding!
[Error Code when trying to import sympy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Q9t.png)

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}`) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Ah okay; I apologize. This is my first time using Stack Overflow.  I will keep this in mind the next time I need to post something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading the version of sympy you are using

```
pip install -U sympy
```

Comment: Just tried and it works! Thank you! In the future, how can one determine if a package isn't working due to it not being the latest version? Like, in this case, I wouldn't have known that the solution was to update sympy.

Comment: @PhysicsProgrammer the error entirely comes from the source code. So, it must be figured out in the later versions and the bug might have got fixed.